# OpenCV Java connect DCS-932L

Tags: java, opencv, camera

I have tryed to connect a D-Link Camera model DCS-932L with openCV uncessfully. I think the problem is with the URL format. The IP, port, password and user are correct.

this is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String end = "http://USER:PWD@IPADDRESS:80/mjpeg.cgi?user=USERNAME&password=PWD&channel=0&.mjpg";


    ContainerImagem toc = new ContainerImagem();

    Button button = new Button();
    button.addActionListener(null);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Captura de face");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\leonardo\\Documents\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    toc.setSize(2000, 2000);

    frame.add(toc);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Mat webcam_image = new Mat();

    MatToBufImg mat2Buf = new MatToBufImg();
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();

    capture.open(end);

    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        while (true) {
            capture.read(webcam_image);
            if (!webcam_image.empty()) {
                frame.setSize(webcam_image.width(), webcam_image.height());
                MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
                faceDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections);
                for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
                    Core.rectangle(webcam_image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));// mat2Buf, mat2Buf);
                }
                // System.out.println("...............face detected: " + faceDetections.toArray().length);

                if (faceDetections.toArray().length == 0) {
                    // System.out.println("Sorry Face not detected!");
                }
                mat2Buf.setMatrix(webcam_image, ".jpg");
                toc.setImage(mat2Buf.getBufferedImage());
                toc.repaint();
            } else {
                System.out.println("problems with webcam image capture");
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O sistema não conseguiu se conectar com esta câmera.");
    }
    capture.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in this forum which OpenCV doesn't Works properly with stream in mjpg format. In this forum also, I found a code to use with JavaCV, and this worked fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("http://USER:PASSWORD@187.45.142.127:80/mjpeg.cgi?user=USER&password=PASSWORD&channel=0&.mjpg"); 
grabber.setFormat("mjpeg");
grabber.start();

IplImage frame = grabber.grab();
CanvasFrame canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("Camera");
canvasFrame.setCanvasSize(frame.width(), frame.height());
while (canvasFrame.isVisible() && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
    canvasFrame.showImage(frame);
}
grabber.stop();
canvasFrame.dispose();
System.exit(0);
```

}